# Using UserDefaults in viewWillAppear

Tags: swift

I'm setting up the Settings page (in SettingsView class) where users can set «On» / «Off» for the background parallax effect. The selection is saved in `UserDefaults().string(forKey: "parallaxStatus")`. In the `viewWillAppear` of ViewController class, I checked the `parallaxStatus`. If the status of the parallax effect is «On», then this effect is displayed. If the status is «Off», then nothing should happen.

The problem appeared when `parallaxStatus` changed from «On» to «Off» In this case, the parallax effect still displayed before I reload the View. But if parallaxStatus changed from «Off» to «On», the function works well without reloading the View.

Bellow is the code of `viewWillAppear` function. Thanks for any help or hint.

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let parallaxStatus = UserDefaults().string(forKey: "parallaxStatus")

    if parallaxStatus == "On" {

        let min = CGFloat(-40)
        let max = CGFloat(40)

        let xMotion = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "layer.transform.translation.x", type: .tiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
        xMotion.minimumRelativeValue = min
        xMotion.maximumRelativeValue = max

        let yMotion = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "layer.transform.translation.y", type: .tiltAlongVerticalAxis)
        yMotion.minimumRelativeValue = min
        yMotion.maximumRelativeValue = max

        let motionEffectGroup = UIMotionEffectGroup()
        motionEffectGroup.motionEffects = [xMotion,yMotion]

        bgImage.addMotionEffect(motionEffectGroup) } else { }

}
```

Comment: not related to your question but you should use the standard user defaults instead of instantiating  a new one every time your app call this method

Comment: Btw why don't you use a Boolean instead of a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You should use a bool value in userDefaults

```
UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "parallaxStatusOn") // default is false
```

2- `viewWillAppear` is called when you dimiss a presented / poped vc so in your case , you use a settingsView not vc verify it's being called by other KVO or any event driven notifier

3- if the state is on and changed to off , verify you remove the motion effects with if the vc is still appeared ( not deallocated btw do it in else of check )

```
bgImage.motionEffects.forEach { bgImage.removeMotionEffect($0) }
```